# New session on every query Angular 2 Ionic 2

Tags: http, angular, get, ionic2

I got a problem with session GET query on Angular 2, Ionic 2 application. Problem is that I get every time on every query new session when query to server is done. So I can't to store information in session on server because I got different session each time. Here is my code in Ionic 2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    let query = this.http.get('http://192.168.1.2/testdb.php');

    query.toPromise().then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.json());
    });
  }

}
```

On server I got with code for CORS requests which is told my my session id.

```
//Headers to disable CORS request:
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');             
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');           

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(headers_list());       
echo "</pre>";  

echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'session_id' => session_id()));
```

Here is my header information:

[image]

What is can be?

Comment: are you building for mobile? in which case cors will not affect you.. it affects only when you do ionic serve.. in case of session.. you will have to store in device..depending on what type of authentication you are doing..

Comment: I'm doing ionic serve. Problem is that I can't store cookies, because session at every time is new.

Comment: you can use any number of dbs to access and store cookies from header..

Comment: My app is allways sends (I don't know why) settings of new session. Each time I query server.

Comment: http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/ https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/11/04/an-example-of-the-ionic-auth-service-with-ionic-2 google is your friend

Comment: you havent setup anything in your app to save state information or sending auth header in your get request

Comment: I know it, I need to store session information at server. To get session info from server after my manipulations. For example: User is authtorize at my server. Server store the information. I query information that was store and it gets me it from session.

Comment: I ques I know what the problem. I start my server at http://localhost:8080, and try to query with ajax http://192.168.1.2/ server. It's seems to I need to do samething to send set cookie command to store cookies at 192.168.1.2 server, and get information with ajax from it at localhost.

Comment: I am Getting the same error in Angular 7, when i make new request i got nothing in session because is a new Session